# Prove that there is no homomorphism from $\Bbb Z_{16}\oplus \Bbb Z_2$ onto $\Bbb Z_4\oplus \Bbb Z_4$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

> Prove that there is no homomorphism from $\Bbb Z_{16}\oplus \Bbb Z_2$ onto $\Bbb Z_4\oplus \Bbb Z_4$.

**Attempt**:Suppose $f$ is such  a homomorphism.

$\Bbb Z_{16}\oplus \Bbb Z_2/\ker f\cong$  $\Bbb Z_4\oplus \Bbb Z_4\implies |\ker f|=2$.

Now if I take the subgroups of order $2$ of $\Bbb Z_{16}\oplus \Bbb Z_2$ as $\{(0,0),(8,0)\}$ and $\{(0,0),(0,1)\}$ then we are done.

But I am unable to understand why the problem says there can't be any.

Please help.

Comment: Did you try to see which quotients you would get with those subgroups? Hint: How many elements of order $4$ do you have to work with?

Comment: Your first option leaves an element of order $8$ and the second an element of order $16$

Comment: So you have found possible candidates for $\ker(f)$ which contains the right number of elements (you forgot $\{(0,0), (8,1)\}$, though). Next is to see whether the isomorphism actually holds for any of them. Alternatively, show that the kernel of $f$ _must_ contain $(4, 0)$.

Comment: How to see if the isomorphism holds for them or not@Arthur

Comment: @Arthur; I don't know the isomorphism here

Comment: Calculate $\Bbb Z_{16}\times \Bbb Z_2/\{(0,0), (8,0)\}$. See what group it is in terms of products of $\Bbb Z_n$. Do the same for the other kernels. See that none of them can be $\Bbb Z_4\times \Bbb Z_4$.

Comment: @MarkBennet; what it means to leave an element of order $8$

Comment: Well consider the image of $(1,0)$ under your homomorphisms. It starts off having order $16$ - what order does it have in the image.

Comment: It might also help you to deal with questions like this in future to consider how many different abelian groups there are which have order $16$ and how you might distinguish between them.

Comment: @Arthur; I am unable to find the homomorphisms ,Note that any homomorphism $\phi$ is determined by its images on $(0,1),(1,0)$ so $\phi(a,b)=a\phi(1,0)+b\phi(0,1)$

Comment: @Arthur; how do you claim that $(4,0)$ is in the kernel

Comment: @MarkBennet; how to determine a homomorphism from its kernel

Comment: @Maths_Student Because $(4, 0) = (1, 0) + (1, 0) + (1, 0) + (1,0)$. Now use $f$ on that, and consider what order elements in $\Bbb Z_4\times \Bbb Z_4$ could possibly have.

Comment: I think you may need to do some hands-on work on understanding the structure of these groups and the orders of the elements. In finite groups, the order of the image of an element in the image of a homomorphism is the least positive multiple of the original element which is in the kernel of the homomorphism. (In infinite groups elements may have infinite order.)